# Passing object in Optional based on whether value exists in object held

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I understand the below:

```
Optional<User> user = ...
user.ifPresent(this::doSomethingWithUser);
```

if `user` is present, pass `user` to `doSomethingWithUser`.

What I'd like to do, is check whether `user.getName` is equal to `"Sam"`.

If this is the case, then pass `user` to `doSomethingWithUser`.

Is this possible?

Comment: `user.filter(u->u.getName().equals("Sam"))....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
user
  .filter(u -> "Sam".equals(u.getName()))
  .ifPresent(this::doSomethingWithUser);
```